# movableColumns and <select> in customEditor

Tags: tabulator

I have a customEditor with a `<select>` in it. When I turn on movableColumns, and the user clicks the `<select>` and still has the MouseDown as they scroll down the list, the column want to move.

Though I havent looked in the code of Tabulator, I would be willing to bet it on the combination of events of MouseDown and MouseMovement within the element are being triggered (though when I test it with the default editor and "select" text to Copy or Paste, it doesnt trigger it, but that might have something to do with focus() as well)

If I'm careful to click on the `<select>`, release the button, and then move the pointer to the option, the column doesn't attempt to move. Even if after the initial MouseUp, I can then MouseDown and move the pointer all I like, the column wont want to move. So again, I think it has something to do with the `<select>` then taking focus() and the MouseEvents not being propogated up the tree ?

For the moment, I've disabled movableColumns to reduce user frustration, even though I've explained to them the behaviour (do users EVER listen ?!?!) until a solution is found.

Addendum : it's not just MouseClick and MouseMove. if I MouseClick and hold (perfectly) still, a timer fires off and it wants to move the Column.

Comment: please post a link to a JS Fiddle or Code Pen that shows the issue in action

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hsvyc1a8/

Note I've commented out the e.stopPropagation() which stops it bubbling up. But I'm sure that's not the "right" thing to do ...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a `e.stopPropagation()` and a `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` to prevent the event bubbling out of the editor